# What is the preferred method to display local "where to buy" information, IP address or physical address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation

I could base it on IP address, or I could base it on the lat. and long. I retrieve from a user's address.

However, the IP address information I've seen from two leading services looks pretty bad. They both said I was in a different city, and neither one got it right.

On the other hand, if a user is not logged in, I could either base it on their IP, or ask them to create an account.

Has anyone made this decision before?

The application is written in Rails 3. Thank you for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: IP locators can only tell you where a person's ISP is.

Comment: And apparently not very well. I've tried 3 now, with 3 different wrong answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess you pretty much answered the question yourself :)

I'd do it like this:

If the user's address is available, use it. If not, use the IP address to retrieve an approximate location. But in any case, always "ask" the user if that's his correct location, as Address location can fail too.

I see this many times in websites that try to discover which country a user is from, but also display (normally at the top) a little menu where one can manually choose the country in case of failed IP based location.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the IP location as a default, and then allow the user to enter a zip code if they wish the targeting to be more precise.  Having to create an account is too high a bar just to see a list of nearby stores, many users will not perform that much data entry to see a list of stores.

IP location is imperfect-  it can be imprecise, but it also produces great results much of the time.  It's a good default.